# Cordova webview + angular

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, phonegap

im working on a PWA application and using Cordova to compile to Android and iOs.
All the pages work fine in browser (on phone and desktop) but when using the cordova builded app some angular functions are not working anymore.

for example elements which contains *ngIf=.... are not working in Cordova but are working in browser and phone browser.

any suggestions on how to fix this?

Regards.

[Browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyLM5.png)
[Cordova screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlhEf.png)

Comment: Please share some additional details such as error messages, logs, screenshots, etc. to help determine what root cause might be.

Comment: Screenshots are added now, no further logging from cordova or console. that all looks fine